# How to ensure that both test and train sets have the same features using scikit learn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I am trying to predict the unseen data for tickets that be re-occur? I have many categorical variables. These variables could be same or repeated. How do i ensure that the features are the same? The features could differ based on the incoming volume?

```
y=predict_pi.P_I
X=predict_pi.drop('P_I',1)
X=pd.get_dummies(X)
print(X)
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

logReg=LogisticRegression()
logReg.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred_pi=logReg.predict(X_test)
print(pred_pi)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,pred_pi))
test=pd.get_dummies(test)
print(test)
pred_test=logReg.predict(test)

I get the error: ValueError: X has 159 features per sample; expecting 161
```

These two columns are the ones that have categorical values and the features depend on them. The features could increase or decrease.

```
AUDITOR REASON_CODE
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

The number of rows and columns in the train and test data set is below.

```
train - (599939, 9) test - (130314, 8)
```

Train data is for 6 months and test data is for the previous month.
Regards,
Ren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these columns to both test and train before you start the regression, and assign their values to be `0`:

```
extra_cols_train = [i for i in list(test) if i not in list(X)]
extra_cols_test = [i for i in list(X) if i not in list(test)]

X = X.reindex(columns=X.columns.tolist() + extra_cols_train)
X[extra_cols_train] = 0

test = test.reindex(columns=test.columns.tolist() + extra_cols_test)
test[extra_cols_test] = 0
```